# WPF Application with map control and custom map

Tags: c#, wpf, maps, gis, bing-maps

I have a georeferenced orthofotomap of cmentary. There is layers with foto, graves and roads between them.
I'm trying to create WPF application with map control and display map connected  with database that I created. I need to allow user to click some grave and then show a overlay with some personal date and button to navigate to this specific grave using routes that I marked before in other program like QGIS. Is there any way to do is with Bing Maps? Or do you know any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with Bing Maps. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to put foto on the map as overlay, but I don't know how to use my own spatial data instead of bing map's. I just start playing with maps so I don't have to much ideas ...

Comment: Clemens, can you tell me how to do it using bing maps?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to turn your image into a tile layer using a tool like MapCruncher: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22420

You can then add this s a tile layer if hosted on a network or server, or use the following blog and add it as a local tile layer: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/08/24/local-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-wpf/

If your image isn't rotated and doesn't require any stretching, you could also try this approach: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Binding-and-Image-to-a-01a56e48