# How to set a Static Bing Map in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I am using WPF Bing map control. It has multiple map images. But, I need a static single map image.

I read some MSDN articles but it's not working fine.

```
<m:Map Name="myMap"                
           ZoomLevel="10"              
           Mode="Road" ></m:Map>
```

I need to display a single static map file. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd221354(v=msdn.10)

Comment: @AnantDabhi am not using the services. Am directly using the WPF.Map control.

Comment: You mean you already have a map image (in Mercator projection) that you want to use instead of the Bing Maps Tile Layer? Perhaps take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29168324/1136211

Comment: @Clemens am using the bing map control. In that mat having more no of maps (the maps repeated while horizontal scrolling). My target is to show a single and static map.

Comment: Sure, but is that a map image that you already have, or how is it supposed to be provided? Bing Maps works with tiled maps.

Comment: @Clemens yes, Bing maps work with tiled images. While scrolling the map horizontally it shows another map. I need to stop that action and also show a single map in WPF UI. in that map i am going to use Pushpins and route line etc.

Comment: We still don't know what a *single map* is supposed to be. Where is it supposed to come from? Do you already have it, or are you asking for some kind of magic?

Answer (score 0):

The WPF control is designed for interactive map scenarios. If you want just a static image, I'd suggest just using an image control and set the image source to a URL for the static image REST service. See the documentation for the static image service here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-a-static-map.
For example, set the image source to something like this:
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/0,0/2?mapSize=1000,500&key={your key here}
Don't use the SOAP service from the URL mentioned by Anant above, that has been deprecated.